# Java compilation of a .java file without a public class

Tags: java

Okay, so a java source file *must* have at least one public class and the file should be called "class-name.java". Fair enough.

Hence, if I have a class, then the following would compile:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

But what bugs me is that if I remove the 'public' access modifier from the above code, the code still compiles. I just don't get it. Removing it, the code looks like:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

In the above code, since I removed the `public` access modifier, my class has `default` or `package` access, i.e. it can't be accessed from the outside world, only from within the package.

So my question is, how does the above code compile ? The file `HelloWorld.java` in this case does not have a `public` HelloWorld class (only a package-private HelloWorld.class) and thus to my understanding should not compile.

Comment: *"java source file must have at least one public class"* Uh no, [it doesn't need to have anything at all.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7791487/1134080)

Answer (score 11):

> a java source file must have at least one public class and the file should be called class-name.java

Incorrect, a top level class does not have to be declared public. The JLS states;

> If a top level class or interface type is not declared public, then it may be accessed only from within the package in which it is declared.

See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#104285 section 6.6.1.

Comment: Thanks! So are you saying that whoever calls main() calls it from some kind of package context? That is, the caller (the JVM presumably) which calls main() is in the same package as my HelloWorld class?

Just confused! So thanks for taking out time to answer my questions.

Comment: Also, you can define multiple non-public classes in a java file.

Comment: So now my question is: HelloWorld is a package private class within the default class, am I right ? So it should be accessible from within the default package but not from outside the default package, right ?

Thus deducing further, when main() gets called, it must be getting called from *within* the default package, am I right ? Or, whoever calls main() is within the same package as HelloWorld class. Right ?

Answer (score 2):

You can place non-public class in a file, and it's not a bug but feature.

Your problem is on level of packaging, not compile. Because you can compile this file with non-public class, but you can't call it from outside, so it's not working as application base class

Like this:

```
// [+] single file: SomeWrapper.java 

public class SomeWrapper {
    ArrayList<_PrivateDataType> pdt;
}
// [-] single file: SomeWrapper.java 

// [+] single file: _PrivateDataType.java 
class _PrivateDataType {
    // members, functions, whatever goes here
}

// [-] single file: _PrivateDataType.java
```

Comment: Thanks, but my point is not to add a private data type or anything. My question is how does the above code compile and/work since here I have a .java file, but without any public class within it. The only class within it is a package-private class, not a public class.

Comment: And where is problem? You can create another class in same package (with same effect) and use that package-private class.

Comment: Again, my question is not to add any new class within the file. I am only concerned with package private access.

Comment: I edited code, it's not new class within file, but within package.

Comment: My question is completely different from what you are illustrating :) What you are saying is correct, but that is NOT what I want to know. I just want to know why having a package private class within a file still compiles.

Comment: as I said. It compiles because it is valid to have single file with single package-private class. it is similar to private members of class, to have private classes of package.

Answer (score 1):

A main method is just like any other method. The only difference is that it *may* be invoked from the command line with the `java` command. Even if the main method is not visible from the command line, the class can still be used like any other Java class, and your main method may be invoked by another class in the same package. Therefore i makes sense that it compiles.

In Java main function are not special in any sense. There just exists a terminal command that is able to invoke static methods called main...

Comment: So now, the HelloWorld class has package-private accessibility. Thus, whoever calls main (the JVM?) now also has to be within the same package, right ?

Comment: I called directly from a java class then yes. The rules for reflection are however slightly different. With reflection, any non-private method may be invoked. The JVM uses reflection to invoke your main method.

Answer (score 1):

There are valid usages for a non public classes. So the compiler does not give error when you try to compile the file.

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing to wonder about. I suppose this behavior is similar to the one of some C/C++-compiler.

Code like "void main() { /*...*/ }" will be compiled correctly by those compilers, although it is not standards-compliant code. Simply said, the compiler exchanges the "void" with "int".

I think a similar behavior is implemented by the java compiler.

Answer (score -1):

When you do not specify the access modifier of the class (or its field or method), it is assigned "default" access. This means it is only accessible from within the same package (in this case, the default package).

The website [Javabeginner.com](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/introduction-to-java-access-modifiers) has an article on the subject - you should become familiar with access modifiers in Java, either from this site, or others.