# "Can't find class" on Java 1.1.5 on Apple Rhapsody DR 2

Tags: java, legacy, tcsh, beta

I don't know a more suitable place to ask something related to a beta operating system from the late '90s, for developers only.

I'm testing Apple Rhapsody Developer Release 2 from 1998 on a virtual machine on my ordinary x86 system. It comes with JDK 1.1.5, so I wanted to test some basic programs on it. I wrote the usual "hello world" program. It compiles fine, but when I try to run it, it says it can't find the class.

When I tried JDK 1.1.8 (I think) on Microsoft Windows 95, I had none of those problems. I feel like I'm forgetting something stupid.

How do I get Java on this OS to run my classes? Or do I just have to forget it since it's a half-developed operating system? It's nothing important, but it would be cool if it worked.

The picture below shows that I'm in the correct directory, including the file I compiled and want to run. Also, I don't know why it's called "javai" despite that command not existing. If it didn't have the JDK, "javac" wouldn't work, would it?

[image: Java on Rhapsody DR2]

Comment: I suggest you use the release version as much as possible. "Preview 2" doesn't sound encouraging, was it never released?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sorry, I meant "Developer Release 2" (as the title says, it's "DR2" for short), not "Developer Preview 2". Also, yes, Rhapsody was never released to the public. It later stopped supporting x86 processors and became Mac OS X Server 1.0 in 1999.

Comment: Does this maybe solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1279556/896588

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public class test`? Never used anything before 1.3 or so though, just a wild guess.

Comment: @C.Ramseyer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634131/package-private-class-within-a-java-file-why-is-it-accessible

Comment: @AndréStannek This version of Java is too old to have the `-cp` switch. It does have `-classpath`, but if I set it to the current directory (`.`), then it ignores all the other classes needed for Java to work, as it prints out: `Unable to initialize threads: cannot find class java/lang/Thread`. I found the Java classes stored in a .jar file, in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/classes.jar, which isn't recognized as a directory, of course. @C.Ramseyer Setting the class to public didn't work.