# Empty file is a valid Java source file. How it is handled inside the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

Empty file is valid Java source file, but how it is handled inside the JVM?

Answer (score 9):

There is no one-to-one relation between .java-files and .class-files. What you have is a one-to-one relation between *classes* (or *class-declarations*) and .class-files.

A Java-source file with zero class-declarations **will not result in any `.class` files**, so it's not really *handled* by the JVM at all.

```
$ touch Test.java

$ ls
Test.java

$ javac Test.java

$ ls
Test.java
```

---

In the Java Language Specification a Java-source file is synonym with a *Compilation Unit*. The relevant section in the JLS is [7.3 Compilation Units](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.3).

The grammar is described as follows:

> CompilationUnit:
>        PackageDeclaration<sub>opt</sub> ImportDeclarations<sub>opt</sub> TypeDeclarations<sub>opt</sub>
>   ...

The <sub>opt</sub>-subscript says that the part is optional. Since TypeDeclarations is optional, no class-declarations need to exist.

Comment: I emptied a `.java` file (which had source code resulting in a `.class` file) and put just a comment inside (nothing but just the comment). As soon as I saved it in Eclipse, the `.class` file disappeared. I thought it would give an error, but it did not. Thanks for this explanation. *The more you know :)*

Answer (score 3):

javac produces `*.class` files for each which occur in the `.java` file. So - none of them, the compiler just does nothing. Nothing give to a jvm.

Answer (score 1):

An empty source file will create no class files, so there is nothing for the JVM to "handle". And an empty class file (which is not something the compiler will create) is invalid, probably resulting in a ClassFormatError or something like that, if that was your question.