# Why does Java allow us to compile a class with a name different than the file name?

Tags: java

I have a file `Test.java` and the following code inside it.

```
public class Abcd
{
        //some code here

}
```

Now the class does not compile, but when I remove the `public` modifier , it compiles  fine.

What is the reasoning behind Java allowing us to compile a class name that is different from the file name when it is not public.

I know it is a newbie question, but I'm not able to find a good explanation.

Comment: Because Java. (Because it's not public, and doesn't have to follow the same naming convention. Beyond that, you'd need to ask the folks that invented it.)

Comment: I doubt there is a "good explanation". It was a requirement for public classes, but it was deemed unnecessary for non-public classes.

Comment: Seems like a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633631/java-compilation-of-a-java-file-without-a-public-class

Comment: Java file name should always reflect the public class defined within that file. Otherwise cannot be compiled. You can take it like "straight line has always two points".

Comment: Why so many upvotes for this question, first of all its duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633631/java-compilation-of-a-java-file-without-a-public-class

Comment: @ Ramesh : title and content of  this question is better..(than the other similar ones)

Comment: Interestingly, C# does not care about the name of the file and you can have multiple top-level types.

Answer (score 326):

The rationale is to allow more than one top-level class per `.java` file.

Many classes—such as event listeners—are of local use only and the earliest versions of Java did not support nested classes. Without this relaxation of the "filename = class name" rule, each and every such class would have required its own file, with the unavoidable result of  endless proliferation of small `.java` files and the scattering of tightly coupled code.

As soon as Java introduced nested classes, the importance of this rule waned significantly. Today you can go through many hundreds of Java files, never chancing upon one which takes advantage of it.

Comment: +1, this actually provides a *reason*, which is the question.

Comment: +1 for the historical info especially - I suspect that with the advent of nested / anonymous classes, if the same decision were to be made now (not caring about backwards compatibility) it would make much more sense to just allow one top level class per file.

Comment: @berry120 Quite probably, because this allowance complicates the file search when compiling.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik And class discovery by humans, although I still say grep/ack are among your best friends during exploration.

Comment: @DaveNewton Here we meet the "simple" design requirement on Java. Giving the freedom to define classes anywhere brings in the responsibility to do so sensibly.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Come on, we are here in 21 century, IntelliJ Idea has celebrated its 13th birthday. Which grep are you talking about?

Comment: @val It was actually Dave who was talking about grep, but he was talking about the same grep which I, and millions around the globe, use every day.

Comment: @Val Denying that other people would rather use a text editor and CLI tools to develop because you the IDE you prefer exists is just as silly as saying there's no point in creating IDEs because you can do development without them.  Both approaches are used by good developers to create quality code; and the only thing smaller than the odds of all developers settling one one of them and singing kumbaya is the odds that we'll all agree on what the single best programming language is.

Comment: Do you mean that there are advantages to use a text editor instead of designed-for-Java IDE (which also includes your text editor) for java development? Do you mean that text search has advantages over the IDE-based class declaration (database) lookup? What is "your preferred IDE"? Is it a strong argument to say that your plain text editor is not at all inferior to a full-blown java IDE? I understand when "good developers" use low-level programming: they have no choice. Yet, IDE outperforms the plain text editor by all parameters and this is a simple fact. It is not "my preference".

Comment: @Val: Some programmers develop code in multiple languages; in some cases, it may be easier for a programmer to use one IDE for every language than to use a different IDE for each one.

Comment: The combination of Emacs (or Vim, pick your poison) and the Unix shell utilities are perhaps not as everything-at-your-fingertips as a modern IDE, and they're certainly harder to learn, but they have two *overwhelming* advantages compared to every IDE I've ever tried: they never crash, no matter how huge the codebase is, and they can keep up with my typing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot create questions (in programmers.se?). Otherwise, I would like to ask if Java IDEs really limit the programmer's typing speed. They seem to compile in the background mode. So, I believe that the speed limit of IDE is a slander. Secondly, saying that IDEs are buggy and fail as opposed to text editors is a pure manipulation. I have worked with them for 10 years and I do not remember they failing. So, lets mirror: IDEs are bug-free and stable as opposed to emacs. Ok? Thanks for showing us that good java developers are those who spread slanders and dirty manipulations.

Comment: @Val: Some of the best programmers I know prefer Emacs to any IDE. Now, I happen to agree that IntelliJ IDEA is an excellent IDE for developing Java code, but that doesn't mean it's the only way to do so. It's like the inversion of control principle: sometimes you want to write code in a framework (IDE), other times you just want a library (editor). For quick editing tasks, I find that vim is quicker and easier than a big IDE, and it works just as well over SSH as locally. Eclipse and IntelliJ are certainly not fast, even on high-end hardware, especially with a large (100K+ LOC) codebase.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik How do you define a `top-level` class?

Comment: @geek It's the standard term for a class which is not contained within another class.

Comment: @DanielPryden IDEs are painfully slow to start, but I have never experienced any of them lagging behind my (or anyone else's) typing. Eclipse also runs most of the refactorings fast enough that I use them as just a quick way of editing code.

Comment: @Val My experience with IDEs, *without exception*, over the past 15 years - and I do keep trying them, because the cross-referencing they do sure does look shiny - has been (a) they consistently lag a good half a dozen characters behind me, and (b) they crash if asked to load up projects of nontrivial size.  That your mileage varies does not mean I am lying about my experience.  Note: my idea of "nontrivial size" is measured in tens of millions of lines of code, because that's the sort of thing I get hired to work on.

Comment: For the record, this is my measurement while a project (of a mere 200 kLOC, admittedly) is open in Eclipse: 250 WPM sustained over 10 seconds, no lag.

Comment: @geek I have found an [authoritative definition](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/JLS/innerclasses.pdf) of the term *top-level class* and it is different from what I imply above: `Classes which are static class members and classes which
are package members are both called top-level classes.`

Answer (score 81):

The reason is the same as for the door plates. If some person officially resides in the office (declared public) his/her name must be on the door tag. Like "Alex Jones" or "Detective Colombo". If somebody just visits the room, talks to an official or cleans the floor, their name does not have to be officially put on the door. Instead, the door can read "Utilities" or "Meeting room".

[image: Official name or MyClass.java]
[image: Meeting room or Test.java]

Comment: Definitely an interesting analogy; it might be even better with a little bit of explanation of how it relates directly. The OP might have some difficulty making the connection (though I understand it perfectly)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I don't think the analogy really fits since it doesn't model the one public class, sharing the file with several package-private classes. It's like the door plate reading "Heather Santee, Manager", but the room actually containing Heather and her two secretaries.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I shouldn't have gotten involved in this; I am class-A *horrible* at analogies! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I wanted to write it, anyway; you just gave a push :) The analogy also fails to express the most acute concern: just due to this feature the compiler must parse all the files to discover all the classes where otherwise it could just read the directory listing and know the names of all top-level classes.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, the analogy perfectly fits the idea of directory, in the long corridor you can quickly find a person by just glancing on the door plates, you do not need to enter each room and ask.

Answer (score 30):

The Java specification states you can only have at most one public class per file. In this case, the class name should match the file name. All non-public classes are allowed to have any name, regardless of the file name.

Comment: But "what is the reasoning behind Java allowing" us this?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Because it doesn't prevent us :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun But what is the reasoning behind not preventing us?

Comment: @Marko Java allows to have multiple classes defined in the same file (as long as only one of them is public). As all classes within the same package must have a different name, there is no other option than allowing non-public classes to have a name other than the file name.

Comment: My 2 cents: maybe it was designed this way for quicker localization of classes inside classpath. With this convention, inspecting the file names/paths is sufficient for class discovery. Without this convention, the classpath class loader might need to open and parse files in order to find classes

Comment: @isnot2bad Are you saying that we are *not* allowed to declare package-private clasess in their own file?

Comment: You are allowed. But you're not constrained to name them according to the file name.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan That's the rationale to mandate that a public class must be in its own file. The question is about the rationale for the opposite case.

Comment: Well, if the constraint would have been imposed for the opposite case, then one won't be allowed to declare more than one class per file (as this would mean the naming constraint will be imposed to all kind of classes, regardless if public or non-public).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik No, I just say that only one class may be public. Of course, it is not required to have a public class at all. But as all classes must have unique names, only one can match the filename, and that's the public class (if there is one...)

Comment: @isnot2bad Your argument makes sense only after you tacitly assume as obvious that Java allows more than one class per file. However, the question is, if Java already has the restriction of one public class per file, then why does it have the extra provision of more non-public classes per file. Why does it allow more classes in the same file *at all*?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, sure. But that wasn't asked I think. And even if it were - you already gave the answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Having declarations located near the code that uses them can often ease maintenance.  If a class exists purely for the purpose of having some public fields, and the semantics of the fields are dictated by the code that reads and writes them, then having that class be in the same file as the code that reads and writes it will make maintenance easier than having it in a file all its own.

Answer (score 14):

I think allowing them is a prerequisite for nested classes. Anonymous Classes in particular dramatically reduce the number of .java files required. Without support for this, you would need lots of single method interface implementations in their own separate files from the main class they are used in. (I'm thinking of action listeners in particular)

There is a good explanation of all nested classes in the [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) Java tutorial on Oracle's website, which has examples of each. It also has a reason they are useful, which I'll quote:

> ### Why Use Nested Classes?
>
> Compelling reasons for using nested classes include the following:
>
> - **It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place**: If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.
> - **It increases encapsulation**: Consider two top-level classes, A and B, where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be
>     declared private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be
>     declared private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be
>     hidden from the outside world.
> - **It can lead to more readable and maintainable code**: Nesting small classes within top-level classes places the code closer to where it is
>     used.

(emphasis mine)

I am not familiar with Java spec back in the early days, but a quick search shows inner classes were added in Java 1.1.

Comment: What should one do in cases where a type is only useful within another type, but instances of the former type are not associated with instances of the latter?

Comment: Nested classes are the Java 1.2 way of doing lambdas or 'First Class Functions when Everything is An Object'. This is changing in 1.8 Syntax. They're also used when we want to model Algebraic Data Types in Java's Type system.

Answer (score 12):

I look at it the other way round. The natural state of affairs would be for the programmer to pick both the class name and the file name independently. Probably in order to simplify finding public classes from outside a package during compilation, there is a special restriction that a public class be in a file with the corresponding name.

Answer (score 4):

Note that Java is case-sensitive, but the filesystem need not be. If the file's base name is "abcd", but the class is "Abcd", would that conform to the rule on a case-insensitive filesystem? Certainly not when ported to a case-sensitive one.

Or suppose you happened to have a class called ABCD, and a class Abcd (let's not get into that being a bad idea: it could happen) and the program is ported to a case insensitive filesystem. Now you not only have to rename files, but also classes, oops!

Or what if there is no file? Suppose you have a Java compiler which can take input on standard input. So then the class has to be named "StandardInput"?

If you rationally explore the implications of requiring file names to follow class names, you will find that it's a bad idea in more than one way.

Comment: I agree with what you have to say, but I don't know that it particularly answers the question except perhaps to the extent that some of the problems resulting from the naming architecture could be eased by allowing non-public class names to be different from file names.  BTW, with regard to case-sensitivity, if I were deriving a language, in any scope were `Foo` was declared, the identifiers `FOO`, `foo`, `fOo`, etc. would all be "undefined" even if they existed within outer scopes.  Such a design would eliminate the case-sensitivity issue for filenames.

Answer (score 3):

Also one other point that many answers missed to point out is that without the `public` declaration, the JVM would never know which classes' main method needs to be invoked. All classes declared in one .java file can all have main methods, but the main method is run on only the class marked as public. HTH

Comment: This is not correct. You can have a file named two.java with the contents:
class one {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println("Hello!");
  System.out.println("World!");
}
}
Now, when you compile it "javac two.java", you get a class file "one.class" and then when you run "java one", it correctly outputs:
Hello!
World!
It runs because we say "java one", JVM knows to look for a class file "one.class", find the main method in it, and run it.

Your second line is also not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because of a java file can contains more than one class, it may have two classes in one java file. But a java file have to contain a class as the same name as file name if it contains a public class.

Comment: No, that rule is only applicable for public classes.